# Moving windows folder path longer than 255 characters

Tags: file, directory

I am trying to move windows folders whose path is more than 255 chars long through command-line but I get error because of the folder path being too long. I was wondering if there was a tool to move such large folder with nested folders to different drives (from S drive to H drive) and what software I could use to get the location of folders with 255+ characters. So if a folder was located somewhere deep within other folders and this child folder's folder path was longer than 255 chars then the software would tell me what folder path this folder has. Hope I am not confusing but if I am then please ask what you are confused with and I will clarify.

So I am trying to do 2 things here:
1. Move folders with large file paths from one drive to another.
2. Find the location of folders where their file path is longer than 255 chars long.

Is there a software or tool for this that anyone is familiar of?

Basically I have hundreds of nested folders in a file system.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential workaround, you can use the [SUBST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx) command to map a drive letter to a subpath thus decreasing the overall path length to something under the 255/260 limit imposed by Windows API.

One technique for scanning for these paths, is to use the dir command:

> dir   c:\   /s  /b  |  sort  /+256  /r  > LongName.txt

This works because the `sort` command first collates all paths shorter than the `/+256` first, then sorts the remaining paths.  The resulting file has all paths shorter than 256 at the beginning, and then all file paths longer than 256 sorted at the end of the file.  Type `help sort` to see details.

That and many other ideas and utilities are discussed here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/c8xqjKOTuR8

As far as a commercial tool to scan and fix, a quick google search turned up ["TreeSize" by Long Paths](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/long_path_support.shtml).

Comment: I have Tree Size. I have hundreds of folders which have a filepath longer than 255 chars so it would be a pain to look at each one and record it.

Comment: trying that dir command I got the notepad file with ALL of the folder paths of files in that folder :S it does not sort it for some reason.

Comment: The command puts all files in the output, but sorts them so that the files greater than 256 (or whatever number you use) are all sorted to the end of the file. It worked for me on Windows 7.  If you need additional automated processing, checkout the notes in the first post of the google group link above.

Comment: This doesn't work. According to the help for `sort` the parameter /+n specifies the character number to begin each comparison. It doesn't remove longer results of the `dir`command.

Comment: @mrt As I mentioned previously, this does not remove longer results. However, it moves all results longer than the `/+n` parameter to the end of the file, and then sorts them. This is per the `sort` documentation. I'll revise the answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is a limitation in the `cmd.exe` shell.  You might try [Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/).  The lite edition (TCC/LE) is free.